# Raspberry Pi as Access Point (based on systemd/networkd) and Wireguard - Routing issues

Tags: vpn, access-point, systemd-networkd, wireguard

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Buster (which I can't upgrade due to some legacy software packages running on it), configured as an access point.
Incoming connections use the onboard wifi and depending on circumstances either a wifi dongle or LTE stick provide the uplink.
Works well since years.

Now want to add Wireguard tunnel for the uplink, i.e. all traffic either from the Raspberry itself as from stations connected via the access point shall be routed thru Wireguard tunnel.

My configuration works to the extent that the connection to the remote router gets established, I can ping the remote wireguard server and gateway (192.168.25.1) and everything in the remote subnet 192.168.25.XXX.

However all traffic not directly directed at this network (192.168.25.XXX) does not get routed thru the wireguard tunnel but straight thru/out of the network to which the uplink is connected.

I read thru similar topics , e.g. how-to-bridge-an-access-point-with-a-remote-network-by-wireguard-with-the-use-of-systemd-networkd but without success.

As a follow up once it's working - is there a "lightweight" way to temporarily enable/disable the wireguard tunnel?

Following are my .network and .netdev files (192.168.25.203 is the address assigned by the remote router):

```
rbp4:/etc/systemd/network $ cat wg0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=wg0
Kind=wireguard
Description=WireGuardClient

[WireGuard]
PrivateKey = XXXXX


[WireGuardPeer]
PublicKey = YYYYY
PresharedKey = ZZZZZ
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint= AAAAA.myfritz.net:59323
```

```
pi@rbp4:/etc/systemd/network $ cat wg0.network
[Match]
Name=wg0



[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=no
Address = 192.168.25.203/24
DNS = 192.168.25.1
IPForward=ipv4
IPMasquerade=yes
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=true
```

The access point is on 192.168.42.1, the uplink is currently connected via wifi to 192.168.178.1 (a Fritzbox), the router running Wireguard server has IP 192.168.25.1 (another Fritzbox)

This is the output from "route":

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         fritz.box       0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 ulwlan1
192.168.25.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 obwlan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ulwlan1
fritz.box       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 ulwlan1
```

Comment: Probably the default route should be to wg0, then the wireguard server (192.168.25.1/32) should go through the uplink.  Right now it's a little surprising this works at all since directing 192.168.25.1 to wg0 would be a circle going nowhere -- unless you mean that's that's the server's wireguard tunnel address, as opposed to it's real address (ie., the one you would use for the box running the wireguard server but not for the tunnel itself).

Comment: The wireguard server is remote (in relation to the Raspberry), upstream of the uplink. wg0 seems properly connected to this server which spans its local net at 192.168.25.XXX, the server itself sitting at 192.168.25.1

Comment: Just checking that `AAAAA.myfritz.net` != 192.168.25.1.  So, again, if you want to route everything through the wireguard tunnel, the default route should be to the wg0 interface, and the myfritz.net address to the uplink.  I've never used `systemd-networkd`, but hopefully that clarifies and better focuses your problem.   You could try testing that manually via `ip route` or similar, if that doesn't screw up or get screwed up by networkd.

Comment: *"As a follow up once it's working - is there a "lightweight" way to temporarily enable/disable the wireguard tunnel?"* -> Wireguard is very simple to use directly, see `man wg`, but there's no specific command for disabling the tunnel, you just do it the same way as any other virtual interface (eg. `ip link set wg0 down; ip link delete wg0`).  But probably you should look at the docs for `systemd-networkd` first and do it that way.